# get ip address from visitors that has visited specific urls centos

Tags: php, logging, centos, ip

I am running a website on Apache CentOS and last weeks someone really annoys me by hitting random urls or trying to guess the admin page.

The webpage is build in php and in my class deconstructs I am logging every error to a txt file.

In the last weeks I can see that someone is hitting randomly urls or trying to guess the admin pages by hitting random strings as permalinks behind the website url.

Now, I want to know how I can find the IP address of this visitor that is trying to accesd these pages. I already tried to look in var/log/acces_log and error_log, but could not understand nor succeed to find the IP that is trying to access these pages.

Here is a part of my log from this morning:

```
[21.10.2018 10:09][2] require(pages/wp-login.php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/jeremy/domains/mysite.com/public_html/order/index.php on line 303
[21.10.2018 10:26][2] require(pages/delicious.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/jeremy/domains/mysite.com/public_html/order/index.php on line 303
[21.10.2018 10:36][2] require(pages/javascript;.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/jeremy/domains/mysite.com/public_html/order/index.php on line 303
[21.10.2018 10:46][2] require(pages/user.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/jeremy/domains/mysite.com/public_html/order/index.php on line 303
[21.10.2018 10:46][2] require(pages/xmlrpc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/jeremy/domains/mysite.com/public_html/order/index.php on line 303
[21.10.2018 10:52][2] require(pages/contact.asp.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/jeremy/domains/mysite.com/public_html/order/index.php on line 303
```

To make it clear, these errors occur when the page you try to acces does not exist, example:
mysite.com/stackoverflow will lead to require(pages/stackoverflow); failed to open stream....

The website is not running Wordpress btw, it is all written in php.

Comment: `if($_SESSION['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'some.ip.address') { die(); }` in index.php or the "entry" file right up top however, IP sniffing is easily gone around and relies upon this being actually in the entry FILE they are trying to access. Make an array of IPs you want to blacklist and compare against that. You may want to consider adding something like `deny from 123.45.6.7` in the htaccess for each IP you wish to block

Comment: the problem is that I don't know which IP to block, I am looking for a way to find the IP that has visitied these pages from the logs. But not sure how to do that...

Comment: Thing is, this happens to everyone, all the time. You just need to make sure that your passwords and general security are up to standard. Keep backups just in case. I know this may look scary or just plain irritating but it seriously does happen to everyone all the time.

Comment: I know. I am not worried about my website being hacked, I just want know how I can reveal this persons IP address.

Comment: You can from the logs created a specific page that the attacker has not yet tried eg admin.php this should look like a standard login page but does not redirect to any page. Its setup so that no matter the username and password combination entered it will always return false this will keep the attacker busy for a very long time. These are called **decoy pages** and as a bonus you can write a JavaScript code that grabs as much information from the attacker's browser as possible :).

Comment: That's a good one. I am going to implement that! Thnx!